# How can I pass parameter as post to endpoint using RestTemplate in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, post, lambda, resttemplate, nestjs

I am using RestTemplate in my project to make a post request to an endpoint. Basically I have lambda function written in nestjs. I am injecting lambda service in my java project. If `vehicleName if condition` passes, I would like to POST that vehicleName to the `url`. Is there any suggestions on how I can achieve this? I would be testing my application using this command

```
curl -X POST "https://gdxdispatcher.dev.awstrp.net/dispatcher/service/api/message" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"vehicleType\":\"US Mutual Fund,VIP\",\"source\":\"PCS_DATACACHE_TOPIC\"}"
```

Here is my code

```
private void callLambdaService(String vehicleTypesParamValue)
    {
        final String url = "http://localhost:3000/dispatcher/service/api/message";

        final String zMETHOD = "callLambdaService - ";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.POST, vehicleName, String.class);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        VehicleType vehicleName=null;

        String[] vehicleTypes = vehicleTypesParamValue.split(",");
        Set<VehicleType> results = new HashSet<>();
        try
        {
            for (String vehicleTypeParam : vehicleTypes)
            {
                vehicleName =
                        vehicleTypeFactory.getVehicleTypeByIspName(
                                vehicleTypeParam);
                if (vehicleName == null)
                {
                    LOGGER.warn("No codes for products or vehicle types were supplied");
                }
                else if (vehicleName.equals("US Mutual Fund"))
                {
                    LOGGER.info(zMETHOD + "Vehicles provided: "
                            + vehicleName.getIspName());

                }
                else
                {
                    LOGGER.warn(
                            String.format("Unknown vehicle type provided: [%s]",
                                    vehicleName.getIspName()));
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to get vehicletype data", e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: The title of the question does not really match with the description. What is it exactly you want to do? Execute an injected lambda in the `if`-branch?

Comment: Endpoint is what I have as of now for testing locally. Injecting it here would integrate this project with other project

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it...

Comment: Trying to achieve silimar to this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-post-json when vehicleName is equal. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Yes. And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am finding it difficult to use the content of above link for Post to the url. If you could help me out

Comment: Please [edit] your question, include your attempt and the concrete problem.

Comment: @osama you mean `http://localhost:3000/dispatcher/service/api/message/[vehicleName]"` for `POST` something like that? or you mean pass as a body name only? addind parameters? which parameters? add an example and post your result. then we can help you.

Comment: @Turing85 updated my code

Comment: @Oneguy updated my code

Comment: @osama OK, creating an answer... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, following the instructions:

1. Create **headers** which will be a data structure representing HTTP request.

   ```
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   ```
2. Build a **JSONObject** from `org.json` package that is a modifiable set of name/value mappings and put names and values.

   ```
   JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
   requestBody.put("vehicleType", "US Mutual Fund,VIP");
   requestBody.put("source", "PCS_DATACACHE_TOPIC");
   ```
3. Create our **HttpEntity** that represents an HTTP request or response, in this case request consisting of headers and body.

   ```
   HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody.toString(), headers);
   ```
4. Create a new resource by **posting** an object to the given `URI` template. 
   It returns the result as automatically converted to the type specified in the responseType parameter.
   Then we define a `ObjectNode` as our resource and response type as our result.

   ```
   ObjectNode result = restTemplate.postForObject("https://gdxdispatcher.dev.awstrp.net/dispatcher/service/api/message", 
                                                   request, ObjectNode.class);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I am getting some errors. One is ```String cannot be converted to Mediatype``` . Then ```cannot find symbol HttpEntity and ObjectNode```

Comment: mm it is weird, try to changing `headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` `to headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: Adding this did not make any change

Comment: Here `new HttpEntity<>(requestBody.toString()` remove `.toString()`  that is the issue. or please make sure your URL is OK , @osama

Comment: Right it says this ```warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to put(K,V) as a member of the raw type HashMap
                requestBody.put("source", "PCS_DATACACHE_TOPIC");
                               ^
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class HashMap
    V extends Object declared in class HashMap
``` at requestBody.put

Comment: `HttpEntity<JSONObject> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);` this should work, I will update it if it is OK.

Comment: It give the same error. What if JSON is added ```String requestJson =  "{\"vehicleType\":\"US Mutual Fund,VIP,US Institutional Mutual Fund\",\"source\":\"PCS_DATACACHE_TOPIC\"}";``` ?  This did not work

Comment: are you sure using this `import org.json.JSONObject` ?

Comment: Need help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633902/resttemplate-postforobject-not-working-as-expected  Thanks